# What Percent of Neural Network is used while processing a single image

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

What percent (on average) of entire Neural network (say, AlexNet) is actually used while processing a single image.

There should only a very small amount of network that should actually be utilized while processing a single image, i.e. removing some branches of the network should cause no or very little effect on the result. But this an intuitive statement.

Is there any quantitative number or a research around this area?

Comment: Why do you think that only part of a neural network is used to compute the output?

Comment: I like your intuition about a physical/biological and highly optimized system.  That isn't necessarily how the math works.  That isn't necessarily how the software implementation of the math would work, even if the math did work that way.  That isn't necessarily how the hardware implementation would work, even if the math and software worked that way.

Comment: Interesting:  https://ai.googleblog.com/2015/06/inceptionism-going-deeper-into-neural.html   https://www.blog.google/technology/ai/understanding-inner-workings-neural-networks/

Answer (score 6):

That depends on the image. In general the answer is 100%, but in different strengths, depending on both the image and the specific network.

In fact, encouraging full-network usage is one of the objectives of the "dropout" technique. This has been written about extensively in many places, but [this blog post](https://medium.com/@vivek.yadav/why-dropouts-prevent-overfitting-in-deep-neural-networks-937e2543a701) is a nice quick introduction.

I'm not aware of in-depth results on "network utilization", but it might be enlightening to fit a simple network of your own (or download a pre-trained one like AlexNet) and see which neurons activate, and how strongly they activate, for various input samples.